# fitting a L shape (corner) to points to remove outliers

Tags: math, geometry, model-fitting, particle-filter

I am trying to extract the length and width from a set lidar sensor points (pink) as shown in the image below. The points circled in blue and white are actually noise which I wish to eliminated. *[The orange box is the length and width I currently have calculated from the points. As seen, the calculated width is much 1/3 wider than it is supposed to be, due to the noisy points i blue and white]*

I've read some approaches to do corner/rectangle fitting, then discarding x% of the poorest fitting points. This would help me to get rid of the circled points. But so far, after many searches I still cannot find any concrete implementations on how to do this fitting.

Can any provide any suggestions how I can go about doing this? 
[image]

Comment: "the orange box is the calculated box size": what does that mean ???

Comment: Please draw precisely the "corner" that you expect to get. Without this info, it is hard to answer.

Comment: Please draw precisely the "corner" that you expect to get. Without this info, it is hard to answer.